# Can I add a custom like button to a facebook page tab?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I need to add a like button to a page tab application (canvas) which 'likes' the main page to which the page tab belongs. What is the appropriate type of like button to add and is it possible / allowed to have a custom graphic instead of the custom like button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a like button that "likes" the page tab itself (https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxx/app_####) but you can have a like button that "likes" anything else including your main fan page (https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxx)

There is no good way to customize the Like button as far as I found, but you can [disguise it](http://www.esrun.co.uk/blog/disguising-a-facebook-like-link/)